# How to call function once forEach loop is done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have to sort some data based on condition and push it to new array `sortedFiles` , so basically once `forEach` loop is done i want to call `asyncFiles()` function and pass the object to it, but its not happening with below code. Any idea what is implemented wrong or any better approach to achieve this task ?

`filesData` is object that contains files from directory.

ctrl.js

```
if (searchObj.searchEnv === 'stat') {
  stDirectory.readDirectory(function(files) {
    filesData.logFiles.forEach(function(file) {
      var sortedFiles = [];
      var fileDate = new Date(file.fileDate).getTime();
      searchStartDate = new Date(searchStartDate).getTime();
      searchEndDate = new Date(searchEndDate).getTime();
      if (fileDate - searchStartDate > 0 && searchEndDate - fileDate > 0) {
        console.log('File Date', file);
        sortedFiles.push(file);
      }
    }, function() {

      console.log(filesData.logFiles);
      filesData.logFiles = sortedFiles;
      asyncFiles(filesData); // Not being called.
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just sort the original array? You should probably take a lot at array.sort or a 3rd party library such as _ that adds a number of features to arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forEach` is not an asynchronous function that takes an optional completion callback. Just do the stuff after your invocation:

```
if (searchObj.searchEnv === 'stat') {
    stDirectory.readDirectory(function(files){
        var sortedFiles = []; // move this in front of the loop
        filesData.logFiles.forEach(function(file){
            var fileDate = new Date( file.fileDate ).getTime();
            var searchStartDate = new Date( searchStartDate ).getTime(); // add missing
            var searchEndDate = new Date( searchEndDate ).getTime(); //     `var`s
            if (fileDate - searchStartDate > 0 && searchEndDate - fileDate > 0) {
                console.log('File Date',file);
                sortedFiles.push(file);
            }
        });
        console.log(filesData.logFiles);
        filesData.logFiles = sortedFiles;
        asyncFiles(filesData); // Now being called.
    });
}
```

Comment: i am using `readStream.on('end',function(){` to read the file so this error is happening if i invoked outside `forEach` 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Comment: Where, what? There's no `readStream` in your code. Sounds like you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the actual complete code.

Comment: yeah i did not added that piece i thought that is unrelated that point

Comment: asked new question if you want to help there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528718/how-to-resolve-foreach-error-on-readstream-file

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` doesn't take 2 functions as Parameters.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) below is the Syntax for the `forEach` Function.

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    //your iterator
}[, thisArg]);
```

So, the second function is being ignored and doesn't make sense. Since, you are not doing any async operation in `forEach`. Therefore you can rely that once the forEach is complete the required work is done and it is safe to call the function `asyncFiles` after completing the forEach Function.

```
if (searchObj.searchEnv === 'stat') {
        stDirectory.readDirectory(function(files){
        filesData.logFiles.forEach(function(file){
            var sortedFiles = [];
            var fileDate = new Date( file.fileDate ).getTime();
            searchStartDate = new Date( searchStartDate ).getTime();
            searchEndDate = new Date( searchEndDate ).getTime();
                 if (fileDate - searchStartDate > 0 && searchEndDate - fileDate > 0) {
                        console.log('File Date',file);
                        sortedFiles.push(file);
                  }
              });


              console.log(filesData.logFiles);
              filesData.logFiles = sortedFiles;
              asyncFiles(filesData); // Not being called.


        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code example asyncFiles is not called because forEach takes 1 arg not 2 but if you want to call a function after a forEach loop that is doing async calls then you can use the map function in [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map

```
async.map(filesData.logFiles, (logFile, next) => {
   // Do some work with logFile
   next();
}, (err, results) => {
   // Call function after mapping is complete
});
```